# Hand written word recognition using Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition, matlab-coder

I am working on a **hand written word recognition** project.

With this project, I have collected sample hand written scripts from several different writers. Hence I have obtained different writing styles.

- For ***segmentation*** and ***labeling*** the following *code* is
  used.

  ```
  I = imread('1.jpg');
  bin_im = imcomplement(out);
  bin_im = bwareaopen(bin_im,30);
  bw1 = bin_im;


  cc = bwconncomp(bw1)
  cc.NumObjects


  %Label the connected components
  [Label,Total]=bwlabel(bw1,8);


  %Rectangle containing the region
  Sdata=regionprops(Label,'BoundingBox');

  for i=1:Total  
  %Crop all the Images 
      Img = imcrop(bw1,Sdata(i).BoundingBox);
      Name = strcat('Object Number:',num2str(i));
      pathname1 = 'C:\Users\sahanpriyanga\Documents\MATLAB\stack\Words';
      baseFileName1 = sprintf('Img%d.jpg',i);
      fullFileName1 = fullfile(pathname1,baseFileName1);
      imwrite(Img,fullFileName1);
  end
  ```

This is the **image** that I have used.

[image]

With this code there are some problems:

1. The labels are not in sequence

Image of the folder of **segmented images**

[image]

2. The lower case letters “ i ” & “ j ”  generate two figures (“ i ”
   gives . and 1 separately )
3. Some letters are segmented incorrectly.

   *like img5 and img6 in the second figure.*
4. The document only contains 61 characters, but after segmentation
       it gives 71 images.

For accurate output I need to modify the project
to resolve these weaknesses and would like suggestions.

Comment: Just to be clear, this (at least from what I can see) is **not** recognizing any characters at all.  You are only **segmenting** the characters.  Before I attempt to answer, please clarify if you actually want to recognize objects as in determine what the written character is, or if you just want to segment the characters.

Comment: No sir I want to recognize the hand written characters. the problems are mention above when I was attending to it.

Comment: The end task is to take the document or display what I wrote by hand as a document.

Comment: The problem here is that some of the characters overlap into areas of other characters. You're using `regionprops` and so if you try and use the bounding box property, you will inevitably get pixels from other characters in the ones you want. If you don't want these, you have to rethink your pipeline... Either do some of preprocessing where you remove extraneous strokes, or don't use `regionprops`. I haven't written an answer because I honestly don't know how to approach your problem.

Comment: what about the problem [1] which I mention above.(refer two images, how can I make segmented images in a sequence order with the hand written document)

Comment: `regionprops` detects blobs column wise as is the nature of MATLAB. You'll notice that each character detected in the order of going up and down, then left to right. Perhaps transpose your image detect the blobs then transpose again.

Comment: Sir, I didn't get the meaning. so can you please modify the code in order to label the segmented images in sequence manner.

Comment: No. I'm not at a computer. Perhaps later.